# How to get date of particular week in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date

I am working on `Rails application` where I am trying to fetch date of particular week but week start from not 1 January of year but some fixed date.

Like, `my week start from 8 july 2016 (08-07-2016)` so now i want to fetch start date and end date of any week.

```
Means week 1 start date -> 08-07-2016 and end date -> 14-07-2016.
```

Now i want to fetch any week start date and end date but how? I already tried but got solution of year start date not like this.

Any one have idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you seen [`#end_of_week`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/DateAndTime/Calculations/end_of_week) and [`#beginning_of_week`](http://apidock.com/rails/DateAndTime/Calculations/beginning_of_week) methods ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok friends,

I found my answer below

```
week = 3
number = (week-1) * 7 
start_date = Date.new(2016, 7, 8) +number.to_i

    d = start_date.to_s.split('-')
    end_date = Date.new(d[0].to_i, d[1].to_i, d[2].to_i) + 6
    end_date = end_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

Let me know if any one have confusion in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to split the start date and create a new date object.

```
start_date_of_first_week = Date.new(2016, 7, 8)
week_number = 3

start_date = start_date_of_first_week + ( (week_number - 1) * 7 )
end_date = start_date + 6
```